# How to find and rearrange texts in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, select, ms-word, copy, range

i have recorded a macro where i remodel a text from .txt file. Ok, after that, what i want to do is to search for a key word, which will find some of this words in the text and then, to select 1 line upwards (always) and, this the tricky part where i couldn't find tips anywhere and why i'm here, the selection below varies and i dont know to set a way to stop. Select all the texts containing the key word and put them together, with the text structure, at end of the page or being able to copy those selected text to be able to paste in other document.

I'm inserting images before and after using the macro, to illustrate what it does and help understand what i need. As you can see, the kew words in this picture are "HAWK" and "OPGW", they are cables used to build electric power transmission lines.  Where one line above refers to the start and end structure to which the "HAWK" or "OPGW" cable is attached to, and for the lines below these key words, it refers to the tension loads submitted and etc..., That's why the variation of lines.

I'm attatching bellow my code which remodels the .txt. I had to cut the middle part of my code, because it was so huge, insanely huge.. we have 5 computers here, so i had to replace the text ".Text = "Cable 'C:\users\XXXX..." for each directory accessed by each computer, that's why is so big haha.

I am a newbie at codding, so i would like your guidance if possible.
Thanks in advance for any help you may provide!

[The text from .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdShv.jpg)

[The text from .txt file after using the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6XAY.jpg)

```
Sub VM_tabestic3()

Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String
Dim Find1stRange As Range, FindEndRange As Range
Dim DelRange As Range, DelStartRange As Range, DelEndRange As Range


Set Find1stRange = ActiveDocument.Range
Set FindEndRange = ActiveDocument.Range
Set DelRange = ActiveDocument.Range


StartWord = "PLS-CADD Version"
EndWord = "Stringing Chart Report"


With Find1stRange.Find
    .Text = StartWord
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False


   Do While .Execute
    
    If .Found = True Then
        
        Set DelStartRange = Find1stRange
        
        DelStartRange.Select

     
        FindEndRange.Start = DelStartRange.End
        FindEndRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

     
        FindEndRange.Select


   
        With FindEndRange.Find
            .Text = EndWord
            .Execute

       
            If .Found = True Then
               
                Set DelEndRange = FindEndRange

              
                DelEndRange.Select

            End If

        End With

     
        DelRange.Start = DelStartRange.Start
        DelRange.End = DelEndRange.End
      
        DelRange.Select

        
        DelRange.Delete



    End If
   Loop
  End With


Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Stringing Chart Report"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Section #^?^?"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "from structure"
    .Replacement.Text = "Est. inicial"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

With Selection.Find
    .Text = " to structure"
    .Replacement.Text = " Est. final"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = False
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Cable 'C:\Users\Usuario\ENGETRAN ENGENHARIA DE SISTEMAS DE TRANSMISSAO\Engetran - Documentos\Projetos\@Projeto Modelo\PLSCADD\Cabos Condutores\CA\1113_0-marigold.wir'"
    .Replacement.Text = "Cabo Condutor: CA MARIGOLD"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With


Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Cable '\\brasil\g\PUBLICA\pls2\Bibliote\Cabos_2009\condutor\starling_acsr.wir'"
    .Replacement.Text = "Cabo Condutor: CAA STARLING "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With


Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Cable '\\brasil\g\PUBLICA\pls2\Bibliote\Cabos_2009\condutor\T-caa_T-rail'"
    .Replacement.Text = "Cabo Condutor: T-CAA T-RAIL"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With


Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Cable '\\brasil\g\PUBLICA\pls2\Bibliote\Cabos_2009\condutor\tern_acsr.wir'"
    .Replacement.Text = "Cabo Condutor: CAA TERN"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With


Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Cable '\\brasil\g\PUBLICA\pls2\Bibliote\Cabos_2009\condutor\violet_aac - Cópia.wir'"
    .Replacement.Text = "Cabo Condutor: CA VIOLET"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With


Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Cable '\\brasil\g\PUBLICA\pls2\Bibliote\Cabos_2009\condutor\violet_aac.wir'"
    .Replacement.Text = "Cabo Condutor: CA VIOLET "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With


Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = False
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Cable '\\brasil\g\publica\pls2\bibliote\cabos_2009\condutor\"
    .Replacement.Text = "Cabo Condutor: "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Cable '\\brasil\g\publica\pls2\bibliote\cabos_2009\pararaio\"
    .Replacement.Text = "Cabo Para-raios: "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Ruling span"
    .Replacement.Text = "Vão regulador"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Sagging data:  Catenary"
    .Replacement.Text = "Dados de flechamento: Catenária"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Condition I Temperature (deg C)"
    .Replacement.Text = "C. Inicial,  Temp. (°C)"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

 Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Condition C Temperature (deg C)"
    .Replacement.Text = "C. Inicial,  Temp. (°C)"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Results below for condition 'Initial RS'"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = _
        "Calculations done using actual span lengths and vertical projections"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "  Span    Mid    Mid"
    .Replacement.Text = "          Mid    Mid"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Length"
    .Replacement.Text = "   Vão"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Results below for condition='I'"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Mid"
    .Replacement.Text = "    "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Span"
    .Replacement.Text = "    "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "  Sag "
    .Replacement.Text = "Flecha"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "           Left "
    .Replacement.Text = "  Suporte"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Vertical"
    .Replacement.Text = "        "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Projection"
    .Replacement.Text = "   Desnível"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Horiz"
    .Replacement.Text = "     "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Tension"
    .Replacement.Text = "Tração "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Struct"
    .Replacement.Text = "    Ré  "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Number"
    .Replacement.Text = "    N°  "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

ActiveDocument.Select
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Font.Name = "Courier New"
Selection.Font.Size = 8

ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:=" Est. inicial", ReplaceWith:="Est. inicial", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="^m", ReplaceWith:="^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="^p^p", ReplaceWith:="^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:=",      .", ReplaceWith:=",", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="  (N)", ReplaceWith:=" (N)", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:=",  Temp.", ReplaceWith:=", Temp.", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="  C. Inicial", ReplaceWith:=", C. Inicial", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="start", ReplaceWith:="^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="^p^p^p^p", ReplaceWith:="^p^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="  Est. f", ReplaceWith:=" - Est. f", Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Dim check As Boolean
 Dim search As String
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim tempStr As String
Dim txt As String

search = "set"

For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    txt = para.Range.Text
    tempStr = LCase(txt)
    check = InStr(tempStr, search)

    If check = True Then
        para.Range.Delete
    End If
Next


ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="Est. i", ReplaceWith:="$ Est. i", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:=", ^p", ReplaceWith:=", $ ^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll

ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="Section ^?^?", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll

ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:=" Est. inicial", ReplaceWith:="Est. inicial", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="^p^p^p^p", ReplaceWith:="^p^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="^p^p^p", ReplaceWith:="^p^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="Est. inicial", ReplaceWith:="^pEst. inicial", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:=" Desnível", ReplaceWith:="Desnível", Replace:=wdReplaceAll

ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="    (N)    (N)    (N)    (N)    (N)    (N)    (N)", ReplaceWith:="    (N)     (N)     (N)     (N)     (N)     (N)     (N) ", Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content


Dim oRng As Word.Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
With oRng.Find
 .Text = "$*$"
 .MatchWildcards = True
 While .Execute
     oRng.Words.First.Delete


     oRng.Words.Last.Delete
    oRng.Bold = True
    oRng.InsertBefore ""
    oRng.InsertAfter ""
    oRng.Characters.Last.Bold = False
    oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
       Wend
      End With
      lbl_Exit:
   Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Comment: General advice: If you find your code is becoming long due to repeated sections, turn that repeated code into a function! Since your `.Find` settings dont change, make a custom FindReplace function that accepts arguments for `.Text` and `.Replacement.Text`. Everything else is pre-set. Then you can shorten your main code from 12 lines per find & replace item to 1 line!!

Comment: Also, if you find yourself doing the same action to a large number of items (Find this, replace with that). You can load all of your items into an array and just loop through the array with that action. Create an array `FindText` and an array `ReplaceText`. Then you can do a loop instead of repeating the code for each item.

Comment: You can use Word's *wildcard* Find/Replace tools to do extensive parsing & reformatting. See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16239-text-manipulation-macro.html, http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?59212-Need-to-Pull-Specific-Data-Text-from-Word-to-Specific-Cells-in-Excel & http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?67346-Import-Words-and-Phrases-from-MS-Word-to-Excel. The latter two export the reformatted data to Excel, but show what is possible. Your links contain only images, not the actual text, so it would be difficult for anyone to take this further.

Comment: @Toddleson could you show me an exemple with my code? bcause i dont get it :x. Sry, kinda newbie here, how can i change it into a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer. The Asker has requested an example of how to implement my suggestions.

Currently, the code is written like this:

```vb
Sub Example()
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "A"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "B"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "C"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

That is 41 lines of code (not counting blank lines) and would take an additional 13 lines of code for each new Find & Replace item.

Instead of repeating this code block for each item, create a sub like this:

```vb
Sub CustomFindReplace(FindWithin As Object, FindText As String, Optional ReplaceText As String = "")
    With FindWithin.Find
        .Text = FindText
        .Replacement.Text = ReplaceText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    FindWithin.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Then your main program can be shortened:

```vb
Sub Example2()
    CustomFindReplace Selection, FindText:="A", ReplaceText:="X"
    CustomFindReplace Selection, FindText:="B", ReplaceText:="Y"
    CustomFindReplace Selection, FindText:="C", ReplaceText:="Z"
End Sub
```

Now instead of 41 lines, we are down to 5 lines of code. Each new item will add one line of code.